# fetch input attributes and make a multidimensional array with index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have some input fields

```
<input class="first" type="text" unique="001" value="2" />
<input class="second" id="001" type="text" value="2" />

<input class="first" type="text" unique="002" value="3" />
<input class="second"  id="002" type="text" value="2" />

<input class="first" type="text" unique="003" value="4" />
<input class="second"  id="003" type="text" value="3" />
```

I want to generate a multidimensional array like this

```
a={
    {value:2, unique:001, value2:2},
    {value:3, unique:002, value2:2},
    {value:4, unique:003, value2:3},
}
```

What i tried is

```
$(".first").each(function() {
  var a={};
  var x=a['value']=$(this).val();  
  var y=a['unique']=$(this).attr('unique');  
  var z=a['value2']=$('#'+y).val();
}) 
console.log(a);
```

I know it doesnt work. Any ideas to solve it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare `a` as an array outside your `.each` code, and then push each object into it. Try this:

```js
var a = [];
$(".first").each(function() {
var x=$(this).val();  
var y=$(this).attr('unique');  
var z=$('#'+y).val();
a.push({value: x, unique: y, value2: z});
});
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="first" type="text" unique="001" value="2" />
<input class="second" id="001" type="text" value="2" />

<input class="first" type="text" unique="002" value="3" />
<input class="second"  id="002" type="text" value="2" />

<input class="first" type="text" unique="003" value="4" />
<input class="second"  id="003" type="text" value="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead and in function create object with target structure.

```js
var obj = $(".first").map(function(){
  return {
    'value': this.value, 
    'unique': $(this).attr('unique'),
    'value2': $('#'+$(this).attr('unique')).val()
  }
}).toArray();
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="first" type="text" unique="001" value="2" />
<input class="second" id="001" type="text" value="2" />

<input class="first" type="text" unique="002" value="3" />
<input class="second"  id="002" type="text" value="2" />

<input class="first" type="text" unique="003" value="4" />
<input class="second"  id="003" type="text" value="3" />
```